# How to safely upgrade an Amazon EC2 instance from t1.micro to large?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, upgrade

I have an Amazon EC2 micro instance (`t1.micro`). I want to upgrade this instance to `large`.

This is our production environment, so what is the safest way to do this?

Is there any step by step guide to do this?

Comment: With EBS root device or with the instance store?

Comment: I think ebs root device. I see EBS under Root Device Menu item on aws console.

Comment: Did any of you consider the fact that a t1.micro, m1.small etc can be 32 bit architecture and that a large instance is 64 bit arc ? Will it not cause any problems ? As of now, I think we will have to do everything again (create a new large instance and install all the application again) ? Is it not the case when there is a change in architecture ?

Comment: That just bit me in the a**. Last time I will choose 32 bit for anything. Now we have a server that needs more memory that 4gb and the 32 bit architecture can't handle it. If fact in the Amazon Control Panel in EC2 there is no option to launch to a large type, it only goes up to medium.

Comment: Why the question is flagged as *off topic*? Its a valid helpful question with acceptable answers.

Comment: My edits got approved, and yet here the question is, still stuck in "off topic" purgatory. Can anyone explain what is required to bring it "on topic"?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

From my experience, the way I do it is create a snapshot of your current image, then once its done you'll see it as an option when launching new instances.  Simply launch it as a large instance at that point.

This is my approach if I do not want any downtime(i.e. production server) because this solution only takes a server offline only after the new one is up and running(I also use it to add new machines to my clusters by using this approach to only add new machines).  If Downtime is acceptable then see Marcel Castilho's answer.

Comment: then delete small the instance before?

Comment: Once your sure everything is running fine, you can delete the other instance if you like(there's no dependency between the two).

Comment: I run an web application on this instance. Until now there was just demo of the application. But since last week our customer started to use intensively. So upgrading is a must.

Comment: IP address of new instance will be different. Am I right? So we need to change dns record ?

Comment: If you are using elastic IP as you should, assign the elastic IP to the new server. The new server will then have the same IP address. This procedure will be useful also if your server crashes and you've to start a new one.

Comment: yes we are using elastic IP's. What is procedure for assign elastic IP to new instance?

Comment: when you launch the new instance..go to the elastic ip section(on the right hand menu) then disassociate the ip with the old instance and then associate it with the new one(these are menu options within the elastic ip section.

Comment: Finally; 1.Create a snapshot of current instance image
2.Launch the new instance as a large instance at that point.
3.Disassociate the ip with the old instance and then associate it with the new one(elastic ip section, we also have elastic ip, This procedure will be useful also if our server crashes and we’ve to start a new one)
4.Once if sure everything is running fine, delete the old instance
(because there's no dependency between the two instance). Ok?

Comment: Yes, thats what I have done in the past and has worked for me!  Good luck!  (p.s. I can't comment too much because I've not set it up fully yet but look into load balancers if you expect alot of traffic..it can spread your traffic automatically between different servers..and using cloudwatch you can spawn new servers if the load becomes too high.  End result is if too much load is on a server, cloudwatch creates another one, and loadbalancer directs traffic there.  Might be something to think about for the future). Good luck!

Comment: I create an ami and then try to launch new instance from that ami. As I said before I want upgrade from micro to large(7.5 GB Memory etc) but there is an problem. The choices are micro, small and high cpu with max 1.7 GB Ram.  
Micro (t1.micro)Up to 2 ECUs1 Core613 MB
Small (m1.small)1 ECU1 Core1.7 GB
High-CPU Medium (c1.medium)5 ECUs2 Cores1.7 GB... Why?

Comment: yikes..I think i know why..I just am not sure if there's any easy way to fix it.  When you setup your server, you set it up as a 32 bit instance.  The large instance is 64 bit(http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)  I had this problem and ended up rebuilding the server, but there maybe an another way. I'm not familiar with the tools but ask the ppl here if there's a way to migrate a server over(some sort of back up/restore tool), build it on a 64 bit micro, and then once your ready follow the above steps you had to move to large.

Comment: now amazon giving zero downtime option

Comment: I had a kernel panic when I did this, I recommend the Change Instance Type method in the other answer.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür was it 64bit to 64bit OS upgrade?

Comment: Of course, it was 64bits to 64bits.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür not sure then, I still follow this approach when I do not want downtime.

Comment: Not a very reliable method, the server state might change if it's under stress (which is very likely considering the need to scale it up), and the new, larger server will be a few minutes/hours older than the actual running server.

Comment: If the snapshot is of the root volume, Amazon recommends stopping the instance before taking the snapshot:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html

Comment: Something to keep in mind is to assign your new instance to the correct security group otherwise even after you switch the elastic IP your new instance won't be visible if the right ports aren't open.

Answer (score 521):

Using AWS Management Console:

- Right-Click on the instance

  - Instance Lifecycle > Stop
  - Wait...
  - Instance Management > Change Instance Type

Comment: this is a way easier method..

Comment: I agree this is simpler, but the benefit of the accepted method is that you could manage to have the new server up and running in parallel to the existing server before switching elastic IP over and incur little or no downtime.

Comment: I did this but HDD space did not increase (Windows 2008 server, x64, micro->large). Tried running Disk Management, but found no unallocated space either. Any ideas?

Comment: Do know that when Marcel says "Wait...", you are going to be waiting for a LONG time. This method is terrible if downtime is an issue. If downtime doesn't matter, it is easy, but this doesn't involve a small amount of downtime. Plan for about a half hour.

Comment: How long (roughly) is the waiting period?

Comment: less than 5 minutes for me...  mw.small to m1.medium running SQL 2012 Web

Comment: And the disk size issue?

Comment: I just changed m1.small to m1.medium, about 2 minutes downtime.

Comment: However well accepted the answer is, process doesn't sound so safe to me. If things go wrong is there a plan B ?

Comment: @abhishek77in: If things going wrong is unacceptable to you, you should go with the accepted answer, which minimizes downtime: create an AMI, bring up another machine, swap out DNS, and then shut down this machine.

Comment: BEFORE you do this, make sure to note the elastic IP of this instance. You will have to manually reconnect it after the upgrade (for some strange reason).

Comment: @RyanMontgomery: Amazon actually discourages taking AMI snapshots of running instances. But then, maybe you shouldn't depend too much on AMIs at all for this process. In any case, it should be noted that all data on instance storage will be flushed when you stop the instance.

Comment: tried to upgrade from t1.micro to t2.micro, however, t2.micro nor t2.small  are available in the drop down list.

Comment: Be noted this will only work when your root device type is ebs. If your root device type is instance store, you should follow Lostsoul's steps.

Comment: As of 2017 the menu has changed to INSTANCE STATE and INSTANCE SETTINGS

Comment: is there a way to do this automatically when the cpu utilization reaches a certain threshold?

Comment: beware! this changes the IP address.

Comment: The easiest and best answer.

Comment: This option do not include new genration EC2 types

Comment: There is no "Instance Management" menu.

Answer (score 48):

**Using the AWS Management Console**

- Go to "Volumes" and create a Snapshot of your instance's volume.
- Go to "Snapshots" and select "Create Image from Snapshot".
- Go to "AMIs" and select "Launch Instance" and choose your "Instance Type" etc.

Comment: This allows you to change architecture and instance type.

Comment: Thanks for actually putting the steps here, and making it clear, this is the best method, unless you are in the early stages where downtime doesn't matter.

Comment: I tried this but in my case new instance didn't start with AMI from older instance, had some kernel panic issue.

Answer (score 17):

Use the AWS EC2 console, not ElasticFox.

First Way:

- **Create a new AMI of the instance**
- **Launch it**

Alternative Way:

- Make a **snapshot** of the disk
- **Launch a large EBS instance** with the same AMI type (please note that at this point the disk will contain the data that was present when this AMI was created, not your latest changes)
- Once is fully booted, **stop the new instance**
- **Detach the root volume** from the stopped instance
- **Create a virtual disk** from the snapshot created before in the same availability zone of the new instance
- **Attach the root volume to /dev/sda1**
- **Start the new instance** again

Answer (score 8):

Create AMI -> Boot AMI on large instance.

More info http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/gsg/2006-06-26/creating-an-image.html

You can do this all from the admin console too at aws.amazon.com

Comment: I want to do this on aws console. is there any howto document with image ?

Comment: Right click on your instance and click "create AMI" - then go into AMIs on the console display (on the left hand side) and click "launch AMI" on the one you want to launch