# What could break after changing instance type on Amazon EC2 AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

That's the generic question.

Edit: Currently machine is m1-small Ubuntu 64bit changing to m1-medium.

Here are some of the components on the box:
    -lighttpd (webserver)
    -fastcgi
    -django
    -gps tracking server (written in python)
    -.com.au domain
    -postgresql
    -postgis

Stackoverflow related [How to change instance type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243307/1547564)

Edit: Upgrade went smoothly - no issues at all. Just took a snapshot of boot volume then changed the instance type after stopping the machine.
I did as expected have to re-associate my public IP address back to the instance using Elastic IP(very easy)
Before doing the upgrade I moved my postgresql cluster(data files) back to the boot volume (since it's small enough) as you can't snapshot instance drives.

Comment: what configuration are you using now and what do you want to change to?

Comment: Currently m1-small moving to m1-medium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are sticking within 64-bit you should be able to stop the instance, change type and then start it again. You will have some downtime, but if you are using an elastic ip it will be minimal. Some caveats however.

1. If you are using instance storage, data on those volumes will be lost.
2. When you restart your instance will be assigned a new public and private ip address. If you are using an elastic ip, it will be disassociated, but you can re associate after the instance has started.

Comment: Thank you for the IP address caveats.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about just changing the instance type, nothing. You should keep backups anyway in case amazon goofs, but remounting the EBS to a larger instance shouldn't break anything as long as you restart all the services and recompile whatever's necessary to be safe.

Comment: You have done it on a production box? The site owner already has some unhappy customers I don't want to add more stress by breaking it. Backup is good tip thanks.

Comment: I migrated a small webserver from t1.micro to m1.small and all I had to do was restart httpd/mysqld services.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did an instance type upgrade from t2.micro to r3.large by creating an image, terminating and then launching...

The image was Win 2012 R2 and I had a static DNS setting which was the DC (not the AWS service, another Win 2012 R2 instance)...

The static DNS setting was lost on the upgrade, so this needed to be reconfigured manually before domain authentication worked again!!