# Upgrading an EC2 m1.Medium into a EC2 m1.Large instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to scale up so I wanted to know if I can upgrade my current 64 bits EC2 m1.Medium instance into a 64 bits m1.Large instance.

Is that the right way to scale up (bare in mind I'm running a small site)?

After I upgrade to the new instance and terminate the old one, will there be a difference between the 2 instances?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you upgrade by stopping your current instance, changing the type and relaunching, there wont be two instances, just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that the right way to scale up (bare in mind I'm running a small
>   site)?

It would work, but to minize risk and downtime some people prefer to create an AMI from their existing instance, then create a new, upgraded instance from that AMI. This way you can test the new instance while the old one is still runing. Once you're satisfied with the new instance, just reassign the elastic IP of the old one to the new one.

> After I upgrade to the new instance and terminate the old one, will
>   there be a difference between the 2 instances?

Other than increased memory, CPU and storage, there should be little difference. The filesystem content should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a precaution, make sure to make a snapshot before you upgrade your instance. Otherwise, yes, it should work just fine. Check out this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898308/how-to-safely-upgrade-an-amazon-ec2-instance-from-t1-micro-to-large)