# `bundle install` fails on EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run `bundle install` after I cloned a repository from github to my EC2 instance, but I'm getting the following error:

```
bundle install
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching git://github.com/EvilFaeton/rubber.git
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:88:in ``': Cannot allocate memory - git clone 'git://github.com/EvilFaeton/rubber.git' "/home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/cache/bundler/git/rubber-505b2994ade5c531df4a62b99e99b8859d168b37" --bare --no-hardlinks (Errno::ENOMEM)
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:88:in `git'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:49:in `checkout'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:144:in `specs'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:52:in `__materialize__'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /home/gbahrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Could someone please tell me why I'm getting this error and how I can fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that the instance was running out of memory. Changing the instance type from t1.micro to m1.small fixed the problem. Downside is that the m1.small instance is chargeable, unlike t1.micro. The instance type can be changed as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898308/how-to-safely-upgrade-an-amazon-ec2-instance-from-t1-micro-to-large). You may also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566223/what-data-is-stored-in-ephemeral-storage-of-amazon-ec2-instance)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

hey a better way to work around this without having to upgrade the instance and for everybody that want to keep using micro they should just add a swap to the instance. There is a very usefull guide  [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 2):

try adding swap to your instance

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04