# Error whilst trying to change instance type in Amazon Web Console EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently trying to upgrade my instance from m1.small to m1.medium and I keep recieving this error:

**An error occurred while trying to change the instance type for this instance**

The process to get to this was by stopping the instance then right clicking and choosing "Change Instance Type", I chose m1.medium from the drop down and clicked apply.

Originally this was a micro instance and earlier today I stopped it and did this same process to move it t a small instance. This all worked fine and the production site came back p when I started the instance again, but, I then realised it still wasn't big enough so that brings me to to this error.

Not sure if it is helpful but the instance is running a Magento production site on Turnkey Linux.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with: `Not sure if it is helpful but the instance is running a Magento production site on Turnkey Linux.`

Also some of the posts from [How to safely upgrade an Amazon EC2 instance from t1.micro to large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898308/how-to-safely-upgrade-an-amazon-ec2-instance-from-t1-micro-to-large) are when AWS didn't even support upgrading the instance type from the console, so take it with a grain of salt.

It could be that the Availability Zone where you are trying to upgrade doesn't support m1.medium instances. Have you tried c1.medium ?

The worse case scenario is that something got fried with AWS and that particular instance.  You can either open a support ticket with them or try recreating the instance by creating an AMI from the instance and then relaunch it with whatever size you want on whatever availability zone you want with the newly created AMI.

I would advise against using 32 bit instance in AWS as they have very limited support.  As you can see in their [instance types page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), the only instance types that support 32 bit are t1.micro, m1.small, m1.medium and c1.medium

Comment: Hello there, thanks for all the help. I have just tried to create an AMI for the current instance and then move it to a new larger one and I get an error pointing me here https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=aaxe8sxcyl34fhr37zt48ansx I think m1.medium isn't supported, trouble c1.medium's memory isn't big enough (you see I need 2GB or upwards). So thats all a little annoying but I shall check out their other options.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess here, but are you by chance trying to upsize a 32bit instance to a 64 bit instance? As far as I know this is not supported.

Comment: I think that m1.medium supports 32bit and that is what i'm aiming for but I shall have a better look because this may well be it. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to Create an AMI and use this to launch the preferred instance or Create a SnapShot of the instance and use it.

This answer has been answered clearly here. [How to safely upgrade an Amazon EC2 instance from t1.micro to large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898308/how-to-safely-upgrade-an-amazon-ec2-instance-from-t1-micro-to-large)